# Print line from file if part of the line is found in Python

Tags: python, file, search

I am trying to write a function that will allow the user to enter a name or phone number, check if it is present in a file, and if it is prints out the entire line in which that element has been found. I have so far:

```
def searchPlayer():
    with open("players.txt") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        print "Enter 0 to go back"
        nameSearch = str(raw_input("Enter player surname, forname, email, or phone number: "))

        if any(nameSearch in s for s in data):
            #Finding the element in the list works
            #Can't think of a way to print the entire line with the player's information
        else:
            print nameSearch + " was not found in the database"
```

The file is formatted like so:

```
Joe;Bloggs;j.bloggs@anemailaddress.com;0719451625
Sarah;Brown;s.brown@anemailaddress.com;0749154184
```

So if nameSearch == Joe, the output should be `Joe;Bloggs;j.bloggs@anemailaddress.com;0719451625`

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: The problem is that `any(...)` doesn't tell you which line matched. Unpack it into a loop andyou'll find it easier to do.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a loop?

```
for s in data:
    if nameSearch in s:
        print s
        break
```

`any` is looping anyway, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: It loops, but it short-circuits (you'd need to add a `break` to the loop to make it equivalent), and in CPython (the reference interpreter) it's implemented in C, which can make it substantially faster than the spelled out loop. Of course, not helpful if it doesn't do what you need. :-)

Comment: You're right, edited - I somehow missed the returns lol, I guess you could also say `return print(s)`

Answer (score 1):

Seems too complicated, just do

```
with open("players.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    if nameSearch in line:
       print line
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `any` as others have mentioned, but you can use `next` if you want to keep the more compact code. Instead of:

```
if any(nameSearch in s for s in data):
```

you'd use [`next` with a default value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
entry = next((s for s in data if nameSearch in s), None)
if entry is not None:
    print entry,
else:
    print nameSearch, "was not found in the database"
```

Note: You might want to use `csv.reader` or the like to parse here, as otherwise you end up mistaking formatting for data; if a user enters `;` you'll blindly return the first record, even though the `;` was formatting, not field data. Similarly, a search for `Jon` would find the first person named `Jon` or `Jonathan` or any other name that might exist that begins with `Jon`.

Answer (score 0):

As @alexis mentioned in a comment, you shouldn't use `any()` if you want to know which line matched.  In this case, you should use a loop instead:

```
found = False
for s in data:
    if nameSearch in s:
        print s
        found = True
        #break # Optional.  Put this in if you want to print only the first match.

if not found:
    print "{} was not found in the database".format(nameSearch)
```

If you want to print only the first match, take out the hash sign before `break` and change `if not found:` to `else:`.